# Evernote Cloud API and C# Console App Error: Unhandled Exception: Thrift.Transport.TTransportException:

Tags: c#, api, evernote

Receiving and error when attempting to get a list of all notebooks in the user's account, with [Evernote Cloud API](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/blob/master/Getting_Started.md). Attempting to have my console application access the Evernote API and simply return the notebooks associated with a user's account.

**Error:**

```
Unhandled Exception: Thrift.Transport.TTransportException: Cannot read, Remote side has closed
at Thrift.Transport.TTransport.ReadAll(Byte[] buf, Int32 off, Int32 len)
at Thrift.Protocol.TBinaryProtocol.ReadStringBody(Int32 size)
at Thrift.Protocol.TBinaryProtocol.ReadMessageBegin()
at Evernote.EDAM.NoteStore.NoteStore.Client.recv_listNotebooks()
at EvernoteSDK.Advanced.ENNoteStoreClient.ListNotebooks()
at EvernoteSDK.ENSession.ListNotebooks_ListNotebooks(ENSessionListNotebooksContext context)
at EvernoteSDK.ENSession.ListNotebooks()
at Evernote_Console.Program.Main(String[] args
```

**Code:**

```
     using EvernoteSDK;

     static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ENSession.SetSharedSessionDeveloperToken("SESSION_DEVELOPER_TOKEN", "SESSION_NOTE_STORE_URL");


        if (ENSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FAIL");
            ENSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS");

         List<ENNotebook> myNotebookList = ENSession.SharedSession.ListNotebooks();



    }
```

The `ENSession.SharedSession.ListNotebooks();` is what is causing the error within my console application. I am simply trying to return all the notes associated with a users account and `Console.WriteLine();` them out. If anyone could provide me with direction as to what this error means or how to solve it that would be wonderful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was within the `SESSION_NOTE_STORE_URL`, after double checking my work - it turns out since I had simply copy & pasted the URL, there was a "." which was appended at the end which caused the error.